# Return value undefined but appears true on console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am attempting to get the return value of a function.

I am doing it like this:

```
  let barHeight;
  componentDidMount() {
    barHeight = StatusBarManager.getHeight(statusBarHeight => statusBarHeight);

    console.log({ mounted: barHeight });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    barHeight = StatusBarManager.getHeight(statusBarHeight => statusBarHeight);

    console.log({ update: barHeight });
  }
```

The curious thing is that if I do:

```
StatusBarManager.getHeight(statusBarHeight => console.log(statusBarHeight));
```

I see how it logs `{height: 20}`, but with both console logs inside those 2 methods: `console.log({ update: barHeight });` all I see is `undefined`.

So how can I grab the value returned by `StatusBarManager.getHeight` in order to use it in another function?

Comment: can you please add `StatusBarManager.getHeight` function

Comment: `let` defines a scoped variable for the brackets. use `var barHeight`

Comment: @Dementic that isnt the problem. The problem is that you aren't waiting for a response to return. You have to `console.log` within the callback of `StatusBarManager.getHeight()`

Comment: @IsaacVidrine that would be true if it was a promise, nothing indicates such though.

Comment: @Dementic the fact that the OPs `console.logs` are undefined tells you that `.getHeight` is an async call

Comment: @IsaacVidrine so by that logic, `console.log(x)` X = Promise? X will be undefined, no matter if its a promsie or not.

Comment: @Dementic im saying that the value of `barHeight` is undefined because OP is logging it out before `.getHeight()` returns with a value.

Comment: @Dementic Just because it doesn't return a promise doesn't mean it's not an asynchronous call that has to be handled appropriately. The fact that the `getHeight()` method takes a callback (and evidently doesn't `return` anything) strongly suggest that it is async.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` always returns `undefined`.You can use following code

```
StatusBarManager.getHeight(statusBarHeight => console.log(statusBarHeight) || statusBarHeight);
```

Comment: I did this but still can't use the value of `statusBarHeight `. I mean I can not grab that value.

Comment: @Reacting Ok now check it.

Comment: @Reacting I think i misunderstood your question. Do you mean that how can you get the value of `statusBarHeight` and also `console.log()` it.

Comment: No, the console.log doesn't matter. What I am saying is that why I get the value `statusBarHeight` on the console.log but not from the value that function returned.

Comment: All I want is the value returned by the function, in this case -> `statusBarHeight`. The `console.log` within the callback is just to show you that I can see the value on thast console.log within there, but it is `undefined` if I remove that console.log.

Comment: @Reacting you aren't returning anything from that function

Comment: @Reacting the value/response from `.getHeight()` is only available within the callback, so to do anything with it, you have to do it inside its callback

Comment: @VLAZ, see my code, I am returning this -> `StatusBarManager.getHeight(statusBarHeight => statusBarHeight);` but the value is `undefined`.

Comment: @Reacting there is no `return` statement, so you are not *returning* anything. You are *assigning* to the `barHeight` variable which is in a shared scope. Two quite different things.

Comment: @Reacting `statusBarHeight => statusBarHeight` is just **your** callback where you simply return the same value it gets invoked with. This doesn't magically make `getHeight` return this value.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `barHeight` is undefined in your `console.log` is because the `console.log` is being executed before the value of `barHeight` is updated with the response from `StatusBarManager.getHeight()`. As you've already noticed, for the `console.log` to work, you have to move it into the `callback` of `getHeight()`.

```
let barHeight;
componentDidMount() {
  barHeight = StatusBarManager.getHeight(statusBarHeight => {
    console.log({ mounted: statusBarHeight });
    barHeight = statusBarHeight;
  });
}
```